# Inserted data Backend

Tags: monaca

Good evening,

I have a very strange problem in Monaca Backend.

When I inserted a data information in Collection Backend with application mobile, I can refer to the information with application mobile.
But when I inserted some information with the Collection Backend website, I can not see the same application with application mobile.

[image: My problem - Picture]

Comment: are you sure that you are using the same backend/collection? It should display it anyway

Comment: Yes, I am inserting information with the mobile application and consulting properly, but when I am inserting with "Add an item" on the website, not consultation.